# IIS 7.5 website application pool with 'full control' permissions hackable?

Tags: iis-7.5, hacking

Although I would never set this permission, I would like to know how a static html website with the permission mentioned in the title could be compromised.

In my humble opinion, I would guess that this would pose no threat since a web visitor has no way to upload/edit/delete anything.

What if the site was a simple PHP website that simply displayed ‘hello world’?  What if this PHP site had a contact us form that was properly sanitized?

Thank you

**EDIT:** I should mention that restricting IIS to GET and POST requests only, otherwise people anybody can delete and upload content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not just with the page, it's also with the engine that hosts the page.

There could be an IIS vulnerability exploited by the GET or POST data in the initial request that exposes data that it shouldn't, before it even gets to the static content. Just like how HeartBleed exposed data from the server memory, regardless of the actual content of the response.

As for PHP - all bets are off. PHP has a long history of vulnerabilities (just like *any* server-side preprocessor does).

I'd say that the dynamic pages your server is serving are a far, far larger attack surface than exploits that don't rely on the server executing a specific page, but that doesn't mean that they don't exist (see again: Heartbleed).

Comment: Although this is would be a bad idea, I have not heard of any 'known' vulnerabilities and nobody as posted any either. If IIS were to allow the PUT command, a bad script or an executable could be uploaded and then executed. I do believe in only providing the most minimal amount of permission to let your app run.